# How to tile an image for Uving in Uv editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm doing some texturing using trim sheets, so a lot of my uving is done off the image on the editor. Is there a way to tile the image so it repeats over and over so I can see where I'm placing things? As of right now I'm guessing where it should be placed and then checking the placement in the 3d viewer.

Answer (score 3):

In the UV editor, Press "N" to open the tab on the right and click view > repeat image